# How to change img style inside span in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I need a quick help:

I have a CSS like this:

```
#ranking li span.awa
{ 
    //Something
}
```

And HTML like this:

```
             <span class=\"awa\"> 
                <div >
                    <a href=''>
                      <img src=''>
                    </a>
                </div>
              </span>
```

Now i don't know what is the name of img and can not put class type to img tag.
I need to set in CSS that img inside span of class awa should have border: 0px; How to do this?

In para langauge i need this:

```
#ranking li span.awa.img
{ 
    border: 0px;
}
```

But it does not work. How to write this properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a space, just like you've used twice. A space means "somewhere inside":

```
#ranking li span.awa img
{ 
    border-style: none;
}
```

`span.awa.img`, my the way, means a span with two *classes*: `<span class="awa img">`.

Answer (score 3):

```
#ranking li span.awa img
{ 
    border: 0px;
}
```

Also note your markup is invalid, `<div>` cannot be a child of `<span>` since it is a block level element.